AWS Private REST API
Dears,
I'm trying to figure out how to make our apis accessible only from my company network.
So basically I'm creating a private REST API and I attach a VPCE with a security group that allows inbound traffic from my private and public ip address but it still does not work.
The security group looks like working fine because I tested with a database and I managed to allow the traffic only from my private IP address, but apparently the same security group doesn't work if attached to the api gateway, so I tried to add also my public one but no results.
Can somebody help me understanding what I am missing here? I'm not an expert here so I might have misunderstood the role of the security groups too.

You seem to misunderstand what a private API gateway is and what a VPCE is and what it is for. Either you have a regular rest API and disallow some wrong IP requests: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-resource-policy-access . Or if you want a private api gateway it will only be accessible from e.g. within a VPC, you can no longer access it from any public IP, see steps 6&7 in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/private-api-tutorial.html#private-api-tutorial-connect-to-instance
